# Compiling CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile CoffeeScript but it fails. I have Node.JS installed, set $NODE_PATH to /home//bin (with my username, of course). That directory contains these files:

```
browserify         coffee@1.1.3                     uglifyjs
browserify@1.10.8  coffee@1.3.1                     uglifyjs@1.0.6
cake               sharejs                          uglifyjs@1.0.7
cake@1.1.3         sharejs@0.5.0-pre                uglifyjs@1.2.6
cake@1.3.1         sharejs-exampleserver
coffee             sharejs-exampleserver@0.5.0-pre
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: node_modules/.bin/browserify: not found
```

How to solve it? Not sure why it checks that directory.

I used "cake webclient" to compile it using the Cakefile.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 x64, compiled ndm from source.

**EDITED as requested:**

I have got a project downloaded from github, which is written in CoffeeScript. I want to run to so I need to compile (build or whatever it is called) it to JavaScript. There is a *Cakefile* in trunk directory of the project. I got there and executed *cake*. It said there are 3 options available to build, one of them was *cake webclient*, so I executed this command. It started converting CoffeeScript files to JavaScript files but then I got that error on one of the files. That is all I know about the situation :D

**EDITED (PATH and NODE_PATH values):**

```
pius@pius-laptop:~$ echo $PATH
/home/pius/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/node/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
pius@pius-laptop:~$ echo $NODE_PATH
/home/pius/bin
pius@pius-laptop:~$
```

Comment: What command are you using that results in that Error?

Comment: what does it mean compile coffeescript ? what file are you trying to compile ? if you need to install coffescript just get it through npm.

Comment: I used "cake webclient" to compile it using the Cakefile.

Comment: You're withholding information. Are you trying to compile a coffeescript file, compile coffeescript or run a CakeFile? Please edit you question and write the exact command you are executing.

Comment: I did and I have commented his answer that it has no effect.

Comment: why cant you say it is sharejs at first place ?

Comment: Didn't know it's question related. I just showed the files in the bin folder and thought that it should be enough. Sorry.

Comment: Never mind. Is there a reason that you need to change $NODE_PATH? Can't you just put the files in the default directory?

Comment: That directory was created by ndm & CoffeeScript installers. I just put that $NODE_PATH definition. What is the default directory supposed to be for these things? I found a couple different paths on the net and they all didn't exist in my computer.

Comment: @Pius All of my modules are in `~/node_modules/.bin`

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you haven't set `$NODE_PATH` correctly because it's looking in the default directory. It should be done like this:

```
export NODE_PATH="/home/$USER/bin"
```

And check it with

```
echo $NODE_PATH
```

EDIT:

Perhaps something needs access to npm. You can try adding that to your path.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin"
```

Also, add these things to your `.bashrc` file and then they'll be available for every terminal. You will need to restart the terminal or execute

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

for the changes to take effect.

Comment: It had no effect. Well, I understand it works differently, but result is the same. And echo prints what it's supposed to print.

Comment: Okay, I've offered another suggestion.

Comment: Nope, no affect. I have updated my first post with a story (my situation). That might help

Comment: @Pius Can you please paste the output of `echo $PATH` and `echo $NODE_PATH`?

Comment: Will add the output in my first message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download a pre-made package for ndm & CoffeeScript in Ubuntu 11.10 x64.  If those work, then the issue is with the way you compile.  If it does not work, then the issue is with your OS install (missing libs, different folders, etc).

Comment: That was my first way of installing ndm. It didn't work. Actually that bin directory was created during the installation of ndm & CoffeeScript